# how to know the exact partition of ubuntu in windows 7

Tags: xubuntu, windows-7, boot-partition

How could I know which partition belongs to Ubuntu and not Windows , when I'm trying to delete the Ubuntu partition ?

Comment: You could take a screenshot of how the partitions look and post it in your question.

Comment: Make sure you have Windows reset as default boot loader in MBR if BIOS or in UEFI if UEFI, before deleting partition.  Grub in MBR requires rest of Ubuntu partition to let you boot Windows from grub.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader From Ubuntu or Live installer, you can see partitions with terminal: `sudo parted -l` All ext4 and swap are part of Ubuntu. Windows is usually NTFS. But with UEFI it also has FAT32 and system reserved.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I can think of is booting up a live cd and then loading Gnome Disks or GParted and then look at the partitions.  If you are still confused at this point you can open Nautilus and look at the contents of the partitions.  This should remove all doubt.  Now remember the size and the id of the partition along with the format structure for example /sdd/sdd1 or /sdd/sdd2 something to that effect.  Once you have these bits of information it should be easy.

Also make sure to always make a backup.  Gnome Disks makes it really easy to back up an entire drive or partition from the live cd to for example an external usb drive.

Here is a howto to make a backup
https://www.maketecheasier.com/backup-hard-drive-gnome-disk-utility/

Answer (score 0):

Windows should show linux partitons in the disk management as "unknown" type since it can't read the filesystem used.

Answer (score -1):

find the partition that isn't formatted as ext4 last I checked,linux doesn't play nicely with a windows partition as "/"